# Placeholder color doesnot change

Tags: html, css

I have applied the below code for my placeholder color to change to white but some how its not working on chrome and chromium v 37.0.X. it works perfectly in firefox.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: #ffffff;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
color: #ffffff;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
color: #ffffff;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #565656;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #565656;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #565656;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #565656;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this link
[Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

There are a few useful answers here.

Comment: I already tried doing that. it works perfectly on firefox, but chrome for some reason is not working